# A creature from Mediterranean

Tags: species-identification

I have recently encountered this red thing on one of the beaches of east Sardinia. It was pretty close to the coast (around 20 meters) and has sticked to one of my fins.

[image: Red creature]

My question is: how is this creature called? Is it dangerous to have skin contact with it?

Comment: Nice picture! I do not know what it is, but I would not touch it.

Comment: How big is it? The perspective makes it hard to tell. (And I agree, very nice picture!)

Comment: It was about 15x15 cm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be an anemone, with the [pedal disc](http://www.nhm.ku.edu/tol/glossary/intro.html) towards the camera. I can't offer a positive ID, but would hazard a guess at genus [Actinia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinia).

Anemones sting, and the stings of anemones range from completely harmless to humans to highly toxic. In the absence of a positive ID, I would avoid poking it.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer, for me it is mostly similar to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beadlet_anemone). Some of the photos [here](https://www.google.it/search?q=Beadlet+anemone&tbm=isch) look very similar too, although I didn't see those blue dots near the tentacles.